# Automating 'yes' prompts running ps1 script in NonInteractive PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to run a `ps1` script in a NonInteractive [Windows CI/CD Runner](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/01/21/windows-shared-runner-beta/).

The script runs several dependency checks, and asks whether the user wants to take action in a dependency is not found.

How would one automatically answer 'Y' to each of these prompts?

Attempts at doing this are not successful:

`ECHO Y | ./node_modules/react-native-windows/scripts/rnw-dependencies.ps1`

As it results in the following error repeatedly until the script is complete:

```
At C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\mobile\application\node_modules\react-native-windows\scripts\rnw-dependencies.
ps1:455 char:48
+ ... r (!$NoPrompt -and (Read-Host "Do you want to install? [y/N]").ToUppe ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Read-Host], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ReadHostCommand
```

The script is from an `npm` dependency so I am unable to make adjustments to it. [GitHub source here,](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows/blob/main/vnext/Scripts/rnw-dependencies.ps1) and source at the time of question:

```
# Troubleshoot RNW dependencies
param(
    [switch]$Install = $false,
    [switch]$NoPrompt = $false,
    [switch]$Clone = $false,
    [switch]$ListChecks = $false,
    [string]$Check = [CheckId]::All,

    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
    [ValidateSet('appDev', 'rnwDev', 'buildLab', 'vs2019', 'clone')]
    [String[]]$Tags = @('appDev'),
    [switch]$Enterprise = $false
)

enum CheckId {
    All
    AzureFunctions
    Choco
    Chrome
    DeveloperMode
    DotNetCore
    FreeSpace
    git
    InstalledMemory
    LongPath
    MSBuild64LongPath
    MSBuildLogViewer
    Node
    RNWClone
    VSUWP
    WinAppDriver
    WindowsADK
    WindowsVersion
    Yarn
    CppWinRTVSIX
}

# CODESYNC \packages\@react-native-windows\cli\src\runWindows\runWindows.ts
$MarkerFile = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\rnw-dependencies.txt"

# Create a set to handle with case insensitivy of the tags
$tagsToInclude = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]([System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnorecase)
foreach ($tag in $Tags) { $tagsToInclude.Add($tag) | Out-null }

# Convert legacy flags to tasks:
if ($Clone) {
    $tagsToInclude.Add('clone') | Out-null;
}

# Handle expansion of tasks
if ($tagsToInclude.Contains('buildLab')) {
    # The build lab needs the same steps as a react-native dev
    $tagsToInclude.Add('rnwDev') | Out-null;
}
if ($tagsToInclude.Contains('rnwDev')) {
    # A react-native dev needs the same as the default
    $tagsToInclude.Add('appDev') | Out-null;
}

$vsComponents = @('Microsoft.Component.MSBuild',
    'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64',
    'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Support',
    'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core',
    'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041');

# UWP.VC is not needed to build the projects with msbuild, but the VS IDE requires it.
if (!($tagsToInclude.Contains('buildLab'))) {
    $vsComponents += 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.VC';
}

$vsWorkloads = @('Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop',
    'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop',
    'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal');

# The minimum VS version to check for
$vsver = "16.5"

$v = [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version;
if ($env:Agent_BuildDirectory) {
    $drive = (Resolve-Path $env:Agent_BuildDirectory).Drive
} else {
    if ($PSCommandPath) {
        $drive = (Resolve-Path $PSCommandPath).Drive
    } else {
        $drive = (Resolve-Path $env:SystemDrive).Drive
    }
}

function CheckVS {
    $vsWhere = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
    if (!(Test-Path $vsWhere)) {
        return $false;
    }

    [String[]]$output = & $vsWhere -version $vsver -requires $vsComponents -property productPath

    if (($output.Count -eq 0) -or (!(Test-Path $output[0]))) {
        Write-Debug "No Retail versions of Visual Studio found, trying pre-release..."
        [String[]]$output = & $vsWhere -version $vsver -requires $vsComponents -property productPath -prerelease
    }
    if ($output.Count -gt 1) {
        Write-Debug "More than one version of Visual Studio found, using the first one at $($output[0])"
    }
    return ($output.Count -ne 0) -and (Test-Path $output[0]);
}

function InstallVS {
    $installerPath = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer";
    $vsWhere = "$installerPath\vswhere.exe"
    if (Test-Path $vsWhere) {
        $channelId = & $vsWhere -version $vsver -property channelId
        $productId = & $vsWhere -version $vsver -property productId
    }

    if (!(Test-Path $vsWhere) -or ($channelId -eq $null) -or ($productId -eq $null)) {
        # No VSWhere / VS_Installer
        if ($Enterprise) {
            # The CI machines need the enterprise version of VS as that is what is hardcoded in all the scripts
            & choco install -y visualstudio2019enterprise
        } else {
            & choco install -y visualstudio2019community
        }
        $channelId = & $vsWhere -version $vsver -property channelId
        $productId = & $vsWhere -version $vsver -property productId
    }

    $vsInstaller = "$installerPath\vs_installer.exe"

    $addWorkloads = ($vsWorkloads + $vsComponents) | % { '--add', $_ };
    $p = Start-Process -PassThru -Wait  -FilePath $vsInstaller -ArgumentList ("modify --channelId $channelId --productId $productId $addWorkloads --quiet --includeRecommended" -split ' ')
    return $p.ExitCode
}

function CheckNode {
    try {
        $v = (Get-Command node -ErrorAction Stop).Version.Major
        return ($v -ge 14) -and (($v % 2) -eq 0);
    } catch {
        return $false;
    }
}

function CheckWinAppDriver {
    $WADPath = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe";
    if (Test-Path $WADPath) {
        $version = [Version]([System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($WADPath).FileVersion);
        Write-Debug "WinAppDriver version found: $version"
        return $version.CompareTo([Version]"1.2.1") -ge 0;
    }
    return $false;
}

function EnableDevmode {
    $RegistryKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock"

    if (-not(Test-Path -Path $RegistryKeyPath)) {
        New-Item -Path $RegistryKeyPath -ItemType Directory -Force
    }

    $value = get-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryKeyPath -Name AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (($value -eq $null) -or ($value.AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense -ne 1)) {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryKeyPath -Name AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense -Value 1 -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}

function GetChocoPkgVersion{
    params([string]$packageId)
    [version]$version = (& choco list --local-only $packageId -r -e).Substring($packageId.Length + 1);
    return $version;
}

function GetMsBuild64BitConfigFile{
    $vsWhere = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
    $msbExeConfigPath=& $vsWhere -latest -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -find MSBuild\**\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe.config
    return $msbExeConfigPath;
}

function CheckCppWinRT_VSIX {
    try {
        $vsWhere = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
        if (!(Test-Path $vsWhere)) {
            return $false;
        }
        [String[]]$vsPath = & $vsWhere -version $vsver -property installationPath;

        if (($vsPath.Count -eq 0) -or (!(Test-Path $vsPath[0]))) {
            Write-Debug "No Retail versions of Visual Studio found, trying pre-release..."
            [String[]]$vsPath = & $vsWhere -version $vsver -property installationPath -prerelease
        }

        if ($vsPath.Count -gt 1) {
            Write-Debug "More than one version of Visual Studio found, using the first one at $($vsPath[0])"
        }
        $natvis = Get-ChildItem "$($vsPath[0])\Common7\IDE\Extensions\cppwinrt.natvis" -Recurse;
        return $null -ne $natvis;
    } catch { return $false };
}

function InstallCppWinRT_VSIX {
    $url = "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/CppWinRTTeam/vsextensions/cppwinrt101804264/2.0.210304.5/vspackage";
    Write-Debug "Downloading CppWinRT VSIX from $url"
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing $url -OutFile $env:TEMP\Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.vsix
    
    $vsWhere = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
    if (!(Test-Path $vsWhere)) {
        return $false;
    }
    [String[]]$productPath = & $vsWhere -version $vsver -property productPath

    if (($productPath.Count -eq 0) -or (!(Test-Path $productPath[0]))) {
        Write-Debug "No Retail versions of Visual Studio found, trying pre-release..."
        [String[]]$productPath = & $vsWhere -version $vsver -property productPath -prerelease
    }

    if ($productPath.Count -gt 1) {
        Write-Debug "More than one version of Visual Studio found, using the first one at $($productPath[0])"
    }


    $VSIXInstaller_exe = Join-Path (Split-Path $productPath[0]) "VSIXInstaller.exe"
    $process = Start-Process $VSIXInstaller_exe -PassThru -Wait -ArgumentList "/a /q $env:TEMP\Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.vsix"
    $process.WaitForExit();
}

$requiredFreeSpaceGB = 15;

$requirements = @(
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::FreeSpace;
        Name = "Free space on $drive`: > $requiredFreeSpaceGB GB";
        Tags = @('appDev');
        Valid = { $drive.Free/1GB -gt $requiredFreeSpaceGB; }
        Optional = $true; # this requirement is fuzzy
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::InstalledMemory;
        Name = "Installed memory >= 16 GB";
        Tags = @('appDev');
        Valid = { (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_computersystem).TotalPhysicalMemory -ge 15GB; }
        Optional = $true;
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::WindowsVersion;
        Name = 'Windows version > 10.0.16299.0';
        Tags = @('appDev');
        Valid = { ($v.Major -eq 10 -and $v.Minor -eq 0 -and $v.Build -ge 16299); }
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::DeveloperMode;
        Name = 'Developer mode is on';
        Tags = @('appDev');
        Valid = { try { (Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense).IsValid } catch { $false }; }
        Install = { EnableDevMode };
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::LongPath;
        Name = 'Long path support is enabled';
        Tags = @('appDev');
        Valid = { try { (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/FileSystem -Name LongPathsEnabled).LongPathsEnabled -eq 1} catch { $false }; }
        Install = { Set-ItemProperty HKLM:/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/FileSystem -Name LongPathsEnabled -Value 1 -Type DWord;  };
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::Choco;
        Name = 'Choco';
        Tags = @('appDev');
        Valid = { try { (Get-Command choco -ErrorAction Stop) -ne $null } catch { $false }; }
        Install = {
            [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072;
            iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'));
        };
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::git;
        Name = 'git';
        Tags = @('appDev');
        Valid = { try { (Get-Command git.exe -ErrorAction Stop) -ne $null } catch { $false }; }
        Install = { choco install -y git };
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::VSUWP;
        Name = 'Compilers, build tools, SDKs and Visual Studio';
        Tags = @('appDev', 'vs2019');
        Valid = { CheckVS; }
        Install = { InstallVS };
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::Node;
        Name = 'NodeJS LTS';
        Tags = @('appDev');
        Valid = { CheckNode; }
        Install = { choco install -y nodejs-lts };
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::Chrome;
        Name = 'Chrome';
        Tags = @('appDev'); # For now this is still required. Edge has been added, but only when it is already running...
        Valid = { try { ((Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe' -ErrorAction Stop).'(Default)').VersionInfo).ProductMajorPart
        } catch { $false } ; }
        Install = { choco install -y GoogleChrome };
        Optional = $true;
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::Yarn;
        Name = 'Yarn';
        Tags = @('appDev');
        Valid = { try { (Get-Command yarn -ErrorAction Stop) -ne $null } catch { $false }; }
        Install = { choco install -y yarn };
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::WinAppDriver;
        Name = 'WinAppDriver';
        Tags = @('rnwDev');
        Valid = { CheckWinAppDriver; }
        Install = {
            $ProgressPreference = 'Ignore';
            $url = "https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/releases/download/v1.2.1/WindowsApplicationDriver_1.2.1.msi";
            Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing $url -OutFile $env:TEMP\WindowsApplicationDriver.msi
            & $env:TEMP\WindowsApplicationDriver.msi /q
        };
        Optional = $true;
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::MSBuildLogViewer;
        Name = "MSBuild Structured Log Viewer";
        Tags = @('rnwDev');
        Valid = { (cmd "/c assoc .binlog 2>nul" )  -ne $null; }
        Install = {
            choco install -y msbuild-structured-log-viewer;
            $slv = gci ${env:LocalAppData}\MSBuildStructuredLogViewer\StructuredLogViewer.exe -Recurse | select FullName | Sort-Object -Property FullName -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
            cmd /c "assoc .binlog=MSBuildLog >nul";
            cmd /c "ftype MSBuildLog=$($slv.FullName) %1 >nul";
         };
         Optional = $true;
    },
    @{
        # The 64-bit version of MsBuild does not support long paths. A temp fix for v16 is: https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/5331
        Id=[CheckId]::MSBuild64LongPath
        Name = "MSBuild 64-bit Long Path Support"
        Tags = @('buildLab');
        Valid = { try {
            [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText( (GetMsBuild64BitConfigFile) ).Contains("Switch.System.Security.Cryptography.UseLegacyFipsThrow=false;Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false;Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths=false")
            } catch { $false }; }
        Install = {
            [ xml ]$msbExeConfig = Get-Content -Path (GetMsBuild64BitConfigFile)
            $msbExeConfig.configuration.runtime.AppContextSwitchOverrides.SetAttribute("value", "Switch.System.Security.Cryptography.UseLegacyFipsThrow=false;Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false;Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths=false")
            $msbExeConfig.Save( (GetMsBuild64BitConfigFile) )
        };
        Optional = $true
    },
    @{
        # Install the Windows ADK (Assessment and Deployment Kit) to install the wpt (Windows Performance Toolkit) so we can use wpr (Windows Performance Recorder) for performance analysis
        Id=[CheckId]::WindowsADK;
        Name = 'Windows ADK';
        Tags = @('buildLab');
        Valid = { (Test-Path "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe"); }
        Install = { choco install -y windows-adk };
        Optional = $true
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::RNWClone;
        Name = "React-Native-Windows clone"
        Tags = @('clone')
        Valid = { try {
            Test-Path -Path react-native-windows
            } catch { $false }; }
        Install = {
            & "${env:ProgramFiles}\Git\cmd\git.exe" clone https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows.git
        };
        Optional = $true
    },
    @{
        Id=[CheckId]::CppWinRTVSIX;
        Name = "C++/WinRT VSIX package";
        Tags = @('rnwDev');
        Valid = { CheckCppWinRT_VSIX; }
        Install = { InstallCppWinRT_VSIX };
        Optional = $true
    },
    @{
        ID=[CheckId]::DotNetCore;
        Name = ".net core 3.1"
        Tags = @('appDev');
        Valid = { try {
            $x = dotnet --info | Where-Object { $_ -like  '*Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1*'};
            ($x -ne $null) -and ($x.Length -ge 1)
        } catch { $false }; }
        Install = {
            & choco install -y dotnetcore-3.1-sdk
        }
    }
);

function IsElevated {
    return [bool](([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).groups -match "S-1-5-32-544");
}

if (!($NoPrompt) -and !(IsElevated)) {
    Write-Output "rnw-dependencies - this script must run elevated. Exiting.";
    exit 1;
}

$NeedsRerun = 0;
$Installed = 0;
$filteredRequirements = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]
foreach ($req in $requirements)
{
    if ($Check -eq [CheckId]::All -or $req.Id -eq $Check)
    {
        foreach ($tag in $req.Tags)
        {
            if ($tagsToInclude.Contains($tag))
            {
                $filteredRequirements.Add($req);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

if ($ListChecks) {
    foreach ($req in $filteredRequirements)
    {
        if ($req.Optional)
        {
            Write-Host -NoNewline Optional;
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host -NoNewline Required;
        }
        Write-Host -NoNewline ": ";
        Write-Host -NoNewline $req.Id;
        Write-Host -NoNewline ": ";
        Write-Host $req.Name;
    }
    return;
}

if (Test-Path $MarkerFile) {
    Remove-Item $MarkerFile
}

foreach ($req in $filteredRequirements)
{
    Write-Host -NoNewline "Checking $($req.Name)    ";
    $valid = Invoke-Command $req.Valid;
    if (!$valid) {
        if ($req.Optional) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow " Failed (warn)".PadLeft(50 - $req.Name.Length);
        }
        else {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red " Failed".PadLeft(50 - $req.Name.Length);
        }
        if ($req.Install) {
            if ($Install -or (!$NoPrompt -and (Read-Host "Do you want to install? [y/N]").ToUpperInvariant() -eq 'Y')) {
                $LASTEXITCODE = 0;
                $outputFromInstall = Invoke-Command $req.Install -ErrorAction Stop;
                if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "Last exit code was non-zero: $LASTEXITCODE - $outputFromInstall"; }
                else { $Installed++; }
            } else {
                $NeedsRerun += !($req.Optional); # don't let failures from optional components fail the script
            }
        } else {
            $NeedsRerun += !($req.Optional);
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " OK".PadLeft(50 - $req.Name.Length);
    }
}


if ($Installed -ne 0) {
    Write-Output "Installed $Installed dependencies. You may need to close this window for changes to take effect."
}

if ($NeedsRerun -ne 0) {
    Write-Error "Some dependencies are not met. Re-run with -Install to install them.";
    throw;
} else {
    Write-Output "All mandatory requirements met";
    $Tags | Out-File $MarkerFile
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming the linked duplicate offers a solution (defining a dummy `Read-Host` function before calling the script that provides fixed responses without prompting); let us know if not.